# How do I stop keychain storing git credentials, permanently and globally?

Tags: git, keychain

Every time I authenticate to github on a shared computer I need to delete my creds from keychain.

Is there a way to permanently turning this off for all repos?

Comment: git config --system --unset credential.helper

Comment: Why do you need to delete them? you can avoid cloning via ssh and use https which will require you to login instead of using your keys

Comment: If the computer is shared, then the settings could also be shared. So you might as well just clean keys up manually.

Comment: A safest option would be to make temporary keys for each session. Like [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/), but it seems to be not working for CLI unless you enable 2-factor authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the credential helper is declared "globally", meaning at your account level.

But if, by shared, you mean "using the same account", then yes, you can

- deactivate the credential helper (generally not set at the system level, only global, so `git config --global --unset-all credential.helper`
- use SSH, with a key per actual user (and setting `GIT_SSH_COMMAND to ~/.ssh/my_actual_private_key`)

That way, even if you are using only one account on the shared computer, you can still reference a credential which references you, and only you.